# Class as function argument

Tags: java

I have a function that filtering list of some values and it use instanseof construction:

```
 public static List<View> getAllChildren(View v) {
    /* ... */
    if (v instanceof Button) {
        resultList.add(v);
    }
    /* ... */
 }
```

I want to make it more general and set Button as function parameter:

```
 public static List<View> getAllChildren(View v, ? myClass) {
    /* ... */
    if (v instanceof myClass) {
        resultList.add(v);
    }
    /* ... */
 }
```

But i don't know how to pass myClass to the function.
Please, tell me how i can generalize this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a class type as a parameter using the `Class` class. Note that it is a generic type. Also, the `instanceof` operator works only on reference types, so you will have to flip it around to get this to work:

```
public static List<View> getAllChildren(View v, Class<?> myClass) {
    /* ... */
    if (myClass.isInstance(v)) {
        resultList.add(v);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

In order to get the `Class` type to be passed in like this, you can simply use the name of the class you want, with ".class" appended. For example, if you wanted to call this method with the `Button` class, you would do it like so:

```
getAllChildren(view, Button.class);
```

Or if you had an instance of something that you wanted the class of, you would use the `getClass()` method:

```
Button b = new Button();
getAllChildren(view, b.getClass());
```

As Evan LaHurd mentioned in a comment, `isInstance()` will check if the two classes are assignment-compatible, so they may not be the exact same class. If you want to make sure they are *exactly* the same class, you can check them for equality like so:

```
myClass.equals(v.getClass());
```

or

```
myClass == v.getClass();
```

will also work in this case, as pointed out by bayou.io

Comment: I would also mention how you get a `Class<?>` object (e.g. `Button.class`)

Comment: It's also worth noting that `myClass.isInstance(v)` will return true if `v` is assignment-compatible with `myClass`. It doesn't necessarily have to be the same class. If you want to test if it's the exact same class, then you can do `myClass.equals(v.getClass())`.

Comment: @EvanLaHurd Thanks Evan, added that in too.

Comment: `==` is fine instead of `equals`. There is only one Class for one class.

Answer (score 3):

If you need more flexibility, you can make your `getAllChildren` method accept any filter using Java 8 lambdas:

```
import java.util.function.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        check(new Integer(1), o -> o instanceof Integer);
        // Prints "That's it".
        check(new Boolean(true), o -> o instanceof Integer);
        // Prints "That's not it".
    }

    static void check(Object o, Predicate<Object> check) {
        if (check.test(o))
            System.out.println("That's it");
        else
            System.out.println("That's not it");
    }
}
```

Or use the Strategy pattern if you prefer, or if Java 8 is unavailable.

For your purpose gla3dr's solution is likely best, but if you need MORE POWER consider these options.

Comment: `Integer.class::isInstance` or `o->o instanceof Integer` :)

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't really familiar with the difference, so I just copied from gla3dr. Reading up on it, it seems `instanceof` is more conventional when the type is known at compile time, so I've edited my answer.